# A few questions on Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, vectors

I actually posted this question a few weeks ago where I wanted my solutions to a few Linear Algebra questions checked. Now thanks to useful links provided by @GerryMyerson I can ask my questions (and verify my answers).

The first three questions I just want solution verifications and suggestions for methods which are faster than the ones I used (also no answers were provided by the creator, so i'm not even sure of the correct answer).

**Question 1**:

Show that the equation:

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8x -6y + 2x + 17 = 0 $$

represents a sphere, and find its centre and radius.

**My Solution:**

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8x -6y + 2x + 17 = 0 $$

By completing the square we have that:

$$((x+4)^2 -16) + ((y-3)^2 -9) + ((z+1)^2 -1) + 17 = 0 $$

Simplifying and collecting we have that:

$$(x+4)^2 + (y-3)^2 + (z+1)^2 = 9 .$$

Since a sphere is an equation of the form:

$$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2$$ where $x_0,y_0,z_0 = (-4,3,-1)$ are the coordinates of the centre of the sphere. Since $r^2 = 9$ the radius is $3$. Our expression can be rewritten as:

$$(x-(-4))^2 + (y-(3))^2 + (z-(-1))^2 = 0,$$ which is indeed the representation of a sphere (I think).

**Question 2:**

Find the area of the triangle with vertices $P(1,-2,3), Q(0,3,1)$ and $R(-1,1,0)$.

**My Solution:**

Since $\vec{PQ} = \langle -1,5,-2 \rangle$ and $\vec{PQ} = \langle -2,3,-3 \rangle$ we take $\vec{PQ} \cdot \vec{QR}$ and have that:

\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k\\ 
-1 & 5 & -2 \\ 
-2 & 3 & -3
\end{vmatrix}

Simplifying we get: $-9i + j + 7k$ therefore $\vec{PQ} \cdot \vec{QR} = \langle -9, 1, 7\rangle$.

$\Vert \langle \vec{PQ} \cdot \vec{QR} \rangle \Vert = \sqrt{(-9)^2 + (1)^2 + (7)^2} = \sqrt{131}$. Therefore using the formula $A = \frac{1}{2}\Vert \vec{v} \cdot \vec{u} \Vert$ we get:

$$A = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{131}$$
$$A = 0.5 \cdot 11.4455$$
$$A = 5.723$$ units squared.

**Question 3:**

Find the volume of the paralelpiped spanned by the vectors $a = \langle 1,2,3 \rangle$, $b = \langle 0,1,-1 \rangle$ and $c = \textbf{i} + \textbf{j}$

**My Solution:**

Vector $\textbf{c}$ can be rewritten as $\langle 1,1,0 \rangle$. Taking the $3\times 3$ matrix we get that:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} = 1 \begin{vmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} - 2 \begin{vmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} + 3 \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = \vert -4 \vert$$

Simplifying the determinant we get that the volume is $4$ units cubed.

Those were the three question's that I need method/solution verification and improvements (if needed) for. I am still a beginner so if you do have any advice could you please explain it in a more fundamental way.

Comment: Near the end of question 1 you got the signs wrong when you tried to fit each into $(v-k)^2$ form where $v$ is a variable and $k$ a constant.

Comment: @coffeemath: Should it be $(x-(-4))^2 + (y-(+3))^2 + (z-(-1))^2$ then?

Comment: In solution 2, I think you mean $\vec{QR} = \langle -2,3,-3 \rangle$...and "we take $\vec{PQ} \times \vec{QR}$" (a typo, your procedure is correct) and $\vec{PQ} \times \vec{QR}=-9\hat{i}+1\hat{j}+7\hat{k}$.

Comment: @Wolgwang: Thanks!

Comment: @DougM: I simplified the determinant incorrectly, thanks for pointing it out.(As well as @wolgwang)

Comment: @Ajay Yes to your comment "should it be---then?"

Comment: @Ajay You should edit your question...

Comment: Yeah I will sorry, I had a class.

Comment: Reason for downvote? Is there something I need to improve on?

Comment: @Ajay I don't know, but would hazard guess that the issue may be the explicitly "compound" nature of the question (i.e., multiple questions are included under a single heading/post). Although people are often naturally reluctant to attempt to post multiples (e.g. because they do not want to be seen as attempting to bother people, or accumulate multiples of reputation upvotes for related queries) there is a site-wide preference for single-subject posts. Putting that issue aside your attempts generally look OK to me and definitely reflect the amount of effort that people like to see. Best wishes

Comment: Ah ok Thank you.

Comment: @Ajay Your answer to question 3 is wrong...the correct answer should be 4.

Comment: @Wolgwang: Wouldn't it be $-4$, or do I have to use the absolute value?

Comment: @Ajay You have to use the absolute value.

Comment: @Wolgwang: Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: rather than looking for fast solutions, crack open the first chapter of calc 3 / last chapter of calc 2, and really get an understanding for what is going on here.  Sometimes students struggle with "what exactly are we looking for, and how does THIS math tell us THAT stuff?"  If you do that, it'll help better in the long run than a fast solution :)  Good luck!!