# Find the center of a circle, h and k, knowing only the radius

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm clueless about mathematics.
I've looked around the internet on how to find the information I'm looking for but I can't find it.

I'm a software dev and I have a problem where I'm going to have circles on a map and the need to find out if a certain point on the map is found inside of the area of that circle.

I've found the formula to calculate it which is $(x−h)​^2​​+(y−k)^2​​=r​^2​​$

**How can you find h and k when you only know the radius ?**

All of the videos I've found show a formula like this: $x​^2​​+y​^2​​+24x+10y+160=0$

But I'm not starting with a math problem, just trying to find these coordinates to be able to know the center of the circle so that I can know if a certain point is inside the circle for which I know the radius since all circles will have the same radius.

Bonus: if you could also share the answer for if I don't know the radius just in case.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're given a formula in the form "$x​^2​​+y​^2​​+24x+10y+160=0$" as you wrote, you can complete the square to try to get $h$ and $k$.

Comment: Obviously, if all you know is the radius of a circle, and you don't know where the circle is, and you don't know where the point is, you don't stand a chance of determining whether the point is in the circle. So, you must have some further information. What exactly do you know about your circle, and what exactly do you know about the point?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, however I meant to say that the only answers I've found were starting with the formula you've given me, but I'm not starting with that problem, just with a circle for which I should know the radius and find h and k with just the radius.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know the spacial coordinates of the circle's center and same for the point as well as the radius/diameter of the circle

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spacial coordinates"? If you know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the center, that's exactly what the letters $h$ and $k$ stand for. Maybe you mean you know the latitude and longitude of the center and the point? In that case, what you are looking for is a formula for the distance between two points, given their latitudes and longitudes. That formula has probably been given  on this website in the past, so you could search for it, and it surely occurs on dozens of internet sites.

Comment: $h$ is the x-coordinate of the circle, $k$ is the y-coordinate of the center.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you. Yes I was talking about the latitude and longitude. Oh I see, you're right the distance makes more sense. however is it still a good idea to try to calculate the fact that a point is inside of the area of a circle using my technique or do you think the distance between two points would be more efficient ? I'd like to know if I went with a solution that way too complicated for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TYeung thank you very much man.

Comment: I don't understand what your technique is. If the distance between the center of the circle and the given point is less than the radius of the circle, then the point is inside the circle; if greater, then outside. What could be more efficient than that?

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for "If the distance between the center of the circle and the given point is less than the radius of the circle, then the point is inside the circle; if greater, then outside" but I couldn't figure it out. Thank you, you can write it as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: This is related to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306461/a-few-questions-on-linear-algebra) I asked a while back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the distance between the center of the circle and the given point is less than the radius of the circle, then the point is inside the circle; if greater, then outside.